# Implement custom update addon for Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I developed my extension for Thunderbird, which is officially approved at https://addons.mozilla.org

I want to implement my custom update mechanism, in case this extension is blocked in the Mozilla repository.

I used this manual and implemented everything strictly according to the instructions - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Updates

I check updates in Thunderbird, the request is `[HTTP / 2.0 200 OK 114ms]`, but the version is not updated and no action is taken.

In tundberbird, I have version 1.0.3 and in the updater.json 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I view console and see error: `Update manifest property 'strict_min_version' has incorrect type`

I change field from: `"strict_min_version": 50` to `"strict_min_version":"50.0"` and update fine work!